# How to find the IQR in the data set using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, iqr

Dataset is below

```
,store id,revenue ,profit
0,101,779183,281257
1,101,144829,838451
2,101,766465,757565
3,101,353297,261071
4,101,1615461,275760
5,101,246731,949229
6,101,951518,301016
7,101,444669,430583
```

Code is below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from pylab import rcParams

df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv',header=None,sep=',')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
dummies = pd.get_dummies(data = df)
del dummies['Unnamed:0']
store = dummies[['storeid']]
test = dummies[['profit']]
qv1 = test[param].quantile(0.25)
qv2 = test[param].quantile(0.5)
qv3 = test[param].quantile(0.75)
qv_limit = 1.5 * (qv3 - qv1)
qv_limit,qv3,qv1
#(688855.5, 776026.0, 316789.0)
un_outliers_mask = (test[param] > qv3 + qv_limit) | (test[param] < qv1 - qv_limit)
un_outliers_data = test[param][un_outliers_mask]
un_outliers_name = store[un_outliers_mask]  
un_outliers_data
```

The output of `un_outliers_data` is `Series([], Name: profit, dtype: int64)`. There are some points which is outliers  like you can see `1615461` > `(776026.0 + 688855.5)`

Comment: what do you really want , you want to know how to find IQR in the dataset, in case of that you can look here https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/summarizing-quantitative-data-ap/measuring-spread-quantitative/v/calculating-interquartile-range-iqr

Comment: @Darkknight  sample data set  url is below https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mak705/Pandas_Projects/master/store.csv